# Ошибка компиляции Android с сторонней библиотекой

Tags: java, android, gradle

При использовании библиотеки 'io.cloudsoft.windows:winrm4j:0.5.0' не получается скомпилировать.
Имею такую ошибку:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveMerger.lambda$mergeMonoDex$0(DxDexArchiveMerger.java:171)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:72)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/logging/impl/NoOpLog;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
    ... 1 more
```

Мой app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.defcore.winrm"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/blueprint.handlers'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'io.cloudsoft.windows:winrm4j:0.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Добавьте в конфиг multiDexEnabled=true, после чего сделайте clean/rebuild. Должно помочь

Answer (score 1):

Вероятнее всего, в библиотеке слишком много методов (свыше 65536). Такой количество не поддерживается андроид при создании dex файла. Вам необходимо разобраться, как заставить компилятор создать несколько dex файлов. Прочитайте, например, эту документацию. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html.
Наверняка, Вы не первые столкнулись с этой проблемой, возможно, Вам получится найти на github урезанную, ужатую библиотеку. Так, мне удалось найти ужатую библиотеку POI

Comment: окуда взялось число *"свыше 50000"*, когда есть вполне определенное - 65536 и связано это с разрядностью счетчика в два байта на количество методов в процессе

Comment: Не судите строго, просто я сам недавно сталкивался с такой проблемой и помню, что данные исключения означает большое кол-во методов и чтобы не соврать, занизил предел, благодарю за поправку, соответствующие изменения внесены в ответ.